# How to map jquery-ui's autocomplete choice to a Java class on POST

Tags: java, jquery, json, jquery-ui, pojo

Say I have this custom Java class `Club.java`:

```
public class Club
{
    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    /* getters, setters */
}
```

Now the jquery-ui autocomplete code:

```
var autocomplete = $('#clubs').autocomplete({
    source: currentClubs
}).data("autocomplete");

if (autocomplete != undefined)
{
    autocomplete._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
        return $("<li>").attr('data-value', item.value).append(item.label).appendTo(ul);
    };
}
```

where `currentClubs` is an array of JSON objects which correspond to the above Java class `Club` ( `{ value : club.id, label : club.name }` ).
This works fine until I submit the form.

I am using Spring MVC Framework, here is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "someMapping", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String someMethod(HttpSession session, Model model, @ModelAttribute("someForm") SomeForm form)
{
    jada jada ...
}
```

where `SomeForm` contains a field `private Club clubChoice`. I would like to map my selected JSON Object to that field. How can I achieve this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it took me another 10 minutes to figure out how to do this.
I changed this part:

```
var autocomplete = $('#clubs').autocomplete({
    source: currentClubs
}).data("autocomplete");
```

to this:

```
var autocomplete = $('#clubs').autocomplete({
    source: currentClubs,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $('#club-id').val(ui.item.id);
    }                       
}).data("autocomplete");
```

where `clubId` is a hidden input:

```
<form:input path="club.name" name="club-name" id="club-name" />
<form:hidden path="club.id" name="club-id" id="club-id" />
```